# How to query for Total of Integer Records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table structured like this;

```
shopid  times
shop1   5
shop2   20
shop1   6
shop1   100
shop2   100
```

My work in progress query;

```
SELECT          
        sum(case when shopid='shop1' then times end) as shop1
        ,sum(case when shopid='shop2' then times end) as shop2     
        ,sum(times) as total
from table3 
group  by shopid
order by shopid
```

Outcome

```
shop1   shop2   total
111     NULL    111
NULL     120    120
```

I need the TOTAL for each records, expected like this. Would you be able to point me to the right direction?

```
       shop1    shop2   total
        111     NULL    111
        NULL    120     120
TOTAL   111     120     231
```

Comment: FYI, it's a that *row* you are after here; not a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use a single query with a single row?

```
select sum(case when shopid = 'shop1' then times end) as shop1,
       sum(case when shopid = 'shop2' then times end) as shop2,
       sum(times) as total 
from table3 ;
```

(You may want `where shopid in ('shop1', 'shop2').)

If you want different rows, then you don't need so many columns.  You can get the total using `GROUPING SETS`:

```
select coalesce(shopid, 'Total'), sum(times)
from table3
group by grouping sets ( (shopid), () );
```

EDIT:

Or if you really want you can do:

```
select (case when shopid is null then 'Total' end),
       sum(case when shopid = 'shop1' then times end) as shop1,
       sum(case when shopid = 'shop2' then times end) as shop2,
       sum(times) as total 
from table3 
group by grouping sets ( (shopid), () );
```

Comment: @qp211 . . . That seems like a silly result set to me, much more verbose than necessary, but I edited the answer.